# "It just comes down to a matter of taste" meaning

Tags: meaning, sentence

I was reading one of the articles where I found a sentence & I am not able to judge the meaning of that. Can somebody tell me what exactly is "**It just comes down to a matter of taste**"

Full-sentence:

*Both have the same functionality and can do the exact same thing, it just comes down to a matter of taste.*

Comment: The usual metaphor would be - "...it just boils down to a matter of taste".

Comment: Look up "come down to" + "meaning".

Comment: Click "close" above and look at the bottom option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "It just comes down to a matter of taste"

**"It just comes down to"**

Means you could argue all week but there really is nothing between them, they are both equal in good points and bad points so neither side will win the argument.

**"a matter of taste"**
Obviously started as a food description do you prefer your steak rare or well done "it is all a matter of taste" but has now been expanded to cover any area where there is no subjective difference just personal preference.

you could write **4+4+4** or **4*3** it is just a matter of taste.

Comment: I got your point for "matter of test". But for "It just comes down to" you might be correct, however i feel something is strange either the formation of both 2 phrases  "It just comes down to a matter of taste" or your explanation.

Comment: @PriyankaAgrawal **It just comes down to** means "it's a flip of the coin." It's arbitrary—or random. There's nothing that's significantly swaying the result one way or the other.

Comment: @Jason, you explained well. Now it hit upon my mind.

Answer (score 2):

It denotes personal preference or style.

Based on the original author's usage, I would take it as: *Both do the same, the choice is based on the user's preference*.

Comment: What does it mean comes down? We could say matter of test instead of saying comes down & word test instead of choice.